# pass java object to bootstrap modal

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap-3, jstl

i'm trying to pass a java object to be displayed in my bootstrap modal...In each row of my datatable i have this code :

```
<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-warning edit"  data-toggle="modal" data-whatever="${u}" data-target="#exampleModal">
```

Where `${u}` is my object to be displayed....
I tried this jquery code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
   var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
 var modal = $(this);
modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient);
modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient);
```

});

It's showing something like in this picture [modal picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv2dK.png)

I don't know if there is a way do display each property of the object in each field...i googled a lot without success...Does anyone have an idea ??Thanks

Comment: just to say that i never used jquery with java before :)!!!

Comment: i visited this link https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/nxL8jezp which is very intersting but really want to proceed with object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are assigning an object to the data.whatever="${u}", but since objects don't exist in HTML the way they do in Java for example, your object is being turned into a String when the page is sent to the client.
I'm guessing what you intend to do is to have each one of the inputs have a different field on the same object. If that is the case, then you would want to have data.whatever = "${u.fieldName}" and you can have a different fieldName for each one of your inputs in your modal.

Comment: Hi John, i tried sending each field like you explain by doing data-id="" data-firstname="" data-lastname="" and it worked fine....Thanks a lot